# What is the correct http status code for a custom login page?

Tags: http, authentication, http-status-codes

I have restricted pages on my website, for example with the URL http://example.com/some-private-article.html, it shows a login page where you have to enter your credentials to see the page.

The information is not gone, it is there but access to it is denied.

I would give a 401 response, but there is no http auth / digest while the spec says that it's required, the login procedure is handled server side with php.

What would be the correct HTTP status code for this kind of page?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

1. Redirect unauthorized user onto login page (which has **different** url).
2. On your private article url 200 OK for authorized user who has access.
3. And 403 for authorized user who doesn't have access.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTTP status code spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) I should use 403 or 404 for a custom login page if the user does not have access already, (is not logged in or does not have the required permission) and has to login to the webpage through the form, external clients will have to login by sending a POST request (Through a HTTPS connection) with the credentials and then storing the cookie with the session key that will allow them to view restricted content after reloading the page.

On the other hand, if I want to make the login page available for scripts through a GET type request or for clients that don't necessarily have cookies or so that it would be possible to login through an URL like https://username:password@example.com/some-private-article.html then I HAVE to use HTTP auth and don't have a choice in how the login popup will look like in the browser, in this case it is appropriate to use the 401 HTTP status code.

I hope I got this right, if not then please correct me.

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely check out this http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html which defines each response code and what they mean.

For your purposes though I would probably suggest a 401 - Unauthorized.

---

Edit: on second thoughts if you're doing forms style authentication then either a 302 - Found or a 307 - temporary redirect to a login page would probably be a sensible response as you're doing the authentication yourself.

Comment: 402 means "Payment Required" not "Unauthorized". "Unauthorized" is 401 and says "The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header" which is the wrong sort of authentication for this and has been explicitly ruled out by the question.

Comment: D'oh, meant 401, typo... edited answer and then read the question a bit more.